# Managing bitmaps and memory cache in android app

Tags: android, ios, memory-management, bitmap, picasso

We have an application that displays a lot of images in a grid at once
Lets say a grid of 50-60 pictures each one takes a 1/4 of a screen
We use picasso library to manage them.

My current understanding is:

- Once we load the picture it is stored in memory in ARGB8888 format, thus 4 bytes per pixel
- Each picture is 1/4 of the screen, so on 1080 screen this is 960x540x4 ~- 2MB per bitmap
- This means total memory needed to keep 60 pictures is 120MB, which is way more than what can be allocated for picasso memory cache from the app heap (and likely more than the app heap itself on many systems)

Which means that by the time we scroll the grid to the right, pictures on the left are being evicted from the memory cache so when we quickly scroll back to the left we see them being loaded again from disk cache (placeholder is seen for a moment). This is bad user experience, the user expects them to be loaded already.

Somehow on iphone (using SDWebImage library) this was never a problem. I assume iPhone doesn't keep the UIImage in ARGB8888 format, but rather keeps it either compressed as JPEG in memory or uses some internal compressed format their GPU/graphic system can understand.

What am I missing? How are large collections of images usually handled/displayed on Android?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to set a large heap in the AndroidManifest? This feature is available only from Honeycomb SDK

```
<application
    android:largeHeap="true"/>
```